# socket.end() or socket.destroy() to ensure file descriptor is released?

Tags: node.js

I am writing a proxy app in nodejs which handles thousands of concurrent connections inwards and outwards

I want to make sure all idle and unneeded connections get closed properly and their file descriptors get released. If it leaks file descriptors, I would run out of them very fast.

My question is that :

**what is the best solution to make sure a connection gets closed ? socket.end() or socket.destroy() ?**

Currently I am using `socket.end()` but in doc it says it half closes the connection, is there a situation that `socket.end()` doesn't result in closing a connection ? what I am interested in is releasing the file descriptors ASAP.

So what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 2):

`socket.end()` is a much better way to gracefully terminate your connections. `socket.destroy` terminates all of your connections immediately. Also, due to a bug, in most of the cases one had to add `socket.end` after destroy to make it work.
So `end()` is the way to go!